# Delete Multi rows with 2 condition

Tags: sql-server-2008

i have a Table like below

---

CategoryGroup

- int  product_group_id   (PK)
- nvarchar(300) product_group_en_name
- int  parent_group_id

---

now i have table like this

```
product_group_id -- product_group_en_name -- parent_group_id
    1                    Phones                Null   <----  category name
    2                    LapTops               Null   <----  category name
    3                    Nokia x3               1  <---- product under Phones Category
    4                    HP probook             2  <---- product under LapTops Category
```

here what i want (when i delete Category , i want all products under that category delete too)

Comment: Cacade delete is the easiest way to achieve this, but be careful! Cascade deletes can be evil!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the [Cascading Referential Integrity Constraint](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa933119%28v=sql.80%29.aspx):

```
ON DELETE CASCADE
```

which:

> Specifies that if an attempt is made to delete a row with a key
>   referenced by foreign keys in existing rows in other tables, all rows
>   containing those foreign keys are also deleted.

When defining this foregin key `parent_group_id`

Comment: @MarwanAyad - Is this is created in the same table, I mean in your example do you want this `parent_group_id` to be referenced to the same table to the column `product_group_id`? Also, is these parent to children categories are recursive or not?

Comment: yep that what i want and yes it in recursive in parent_group_id

Answer (score 0):

You can sdd foreign key to second table with option DELETE CASCADE. See http://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/2743/using-delete-cascade-option-for-foreign-keys/